# How to only display the text after the third, first, and fifth comma in this order in Unix?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I want to display the text after the 3rd, 1st, and 5th comma from a given input text, in that order.

Doing `cut -d ',' -f 3,1,5` does the job but doesn't keep the order I want.  Instead, it displays the text in ascending order: 1, 3, 5.

Comment: what does `file yourFileName` returns?

Comment: Hoe about a lot more details. Can you give us an example of an input line? Which "unix" are you using and which shell?

Answer (score 8):

The `cut` utility always outputs the fields in the same order as in the input. It is unable to re-order the fields.

Using `awk` in place of `cut`:

```bsh
awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $3, $1, $5 }'
```

This outputs the 3rd, 1st, and 5th comma-delimited fields, in that order.  It uses the same field delimiter for the output as for the input.

Example:

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f" | awk -F , 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $3, $1, $5 }'
c,a,e
```

If you are working with real CSV files that may contain CSV-encoded fields, then use `csvcut` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bsh
csvcut -c 5,1,3  file.csv
```

You may also use column names with `csvcut`, e.g.

```bsh
csvcut -c name,age,address  file.csv
```

See also `csvcut --help`.